# Image and text in block

Tags: html, css

I was thinking how to make this block. But i am stuck. I have no idea how to make so that image will take 25% of left content and other 75% is for text. 
I am using Bootstrap 3.

[IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vxl7z.png)

html:

```css
 .card-profile,
    .card-testimonial {
        margin-top: 30px;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .card {
        display: inline-block;
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
        margin-bottom: 30px;
        border-radius: 6px;
        color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.87);
        background: #fff;
        box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 0 3px 1px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 1px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
    }
    .img-rounded {
        border-radius: 6px;
    }
    .img-responsive {
        display: block;
        max-width: 100%;
        height: auto;
    }
```

```html
<div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="card card-profile">

            <div class="col-md-4">
              <img src="assets/img/faces/avatar.jpg" alt="Rounded Image" class="img-rounded img-responsive">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8">
              Text
            </div>
        </div>
```

In result i am getting this[IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SIzNW.png)

Comment: Can you include some code showing what you have tried so far? Thanks

Comment: I have added code. This code enough?

Comment: Add the css too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is that what you want?

```css
.card-profile,
    .card-testimonial {
        margin-top: 30px;        
    }
    .card {
        display: inline-block;
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
        margin-bottom: 30px;
        border-radius: 6px;
        color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.87);
        background: #fff;
        box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 0 3px 1px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 1px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
        display: flex;
    }
    .img-rounded {
        border-radius: 6px;
    }
    .img-responsive {
        display: block;
        max-width: 100%;
        height: auto;
    }
 .center-text{
  text-align: center;    
 }
  .middle-center{
    top: 50%;
    position: relative;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
  }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
        <div class="card card-profile">
            <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-4">
              <img src="https://orig00.deviantart.net/e4cc/f/2012/142/f/b/_portal_2__black_floor_panel_wall_panel_by_themackenzie-d50qjf0.png" alt="Rounded Image" class="img-rounded img-responsive">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8 col-xs-8 center-text">
              <div class="middle-center">Text Text Text text Text Text</div>
            </div>
        </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Yes. But how do i put this text in middle(Center of block)?

Comment: Answer edited. If this helps you and is the correct answer, please mark it as correct and upvote. Thanks. Next time please try a little bit more

Comment: Sure! Thank you!

Comment: Also have got a quetion. What might conflict that makes col be wrong? http://prntscr.com/hxq3xq

Comment: Please, create a fiddle or codepen with your code than I can analyze. Just with an image it's almost impossible to discover what can conflict

Comment: you created another div around the div with the text, so you changed the parent. You need to keep text directly inside 'middle-center' and that div directly inside the 'center-text', if not that way, you'll need to restructure to middle align it again...